# Conditional recursive search on nested dict based on key and value

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

In terms of SQL, I am attempting to build a dependency graph based on the tables that are utilized in a query. I managed to parse them into a nested dictionary with the depth according to how nested the subqueries are and might differ for each block of nested dict. Given the below example:

```
sql = {"select":{"value":"some value"},
       "from":[{"value":"table1","name":"a"},
               {"value":{"select":{"value":"*"},
                         "from":{"value":"table2","name":"b"}}}]}
```

The expected output is:

```
["table1","table2"]
```

My initial approach was to search recursively for `from` keys with:

```
def recurd(d, find = ['from']):
    if isinstance(d, list):
        for i in d:
            yield from recurd(i)
    elif isinstance(d, dict):
        for k,v in d.items():
            if any(i in k for i in find):
                yield v
        for j in d.values():
            yield from recurd(j)
```

With the output:

```
[{'value': 'table1', 'name': 'a'}, {'value': {'select': {'value': '*'}, 'from': {'value': 'table2', 'name': 'b'}}}]
{'value': 'table2', 'name': 'b'}
```

While this is expected, I am finding it quite confusing to also recursively return the values I want based on key and value. I have tried looking around but it seems that most examples on recursion applied to nested dicts only look at keys, similar to the example I have above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function should keep track of the parent key as it recurses so that it can yield the value only if the parent key is `'from'`:

```
def get_tables(d, find=('from',), parent_key=None):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if parent_key in find and isinstance(d.get('value'), str):
            yield d['value']
        for k, v in d.items():
            yield from get_tables(v, find, k)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for i in d:
            yield from get_tables(i, find, parent_key)
```

so that `list(get_tables(sql))` returns:

```
['table1', 'table2']
```

Comment: Is there a method to search for multiple values and not only `from`? Thanks by the way.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I've updated my answer accordingly then.

Comment: Looks awesome, this should get me on the way, do you think you can explain what happens in the `isinstance` block, I think that is where I get confused where you have a `if then yield` followed by a `for... yield`.

Comment: The important bit here is the `if parent_key in find and isinstance(d.get('value'), str):` condition, to yield the value only if the parent key is `'from'` and the `value` key of the current dict is a string. And when it recurses while iterating thorugh dict items, pass the current key as the parent key of the recursive call, but pass on the same parent key to the recursive call when iterating through a list.